# AVD se estrella en el lanzamiento

Tags: android, avd

Utilizo Android studio. Me gustaría lanzar un AVD pero cuando lo intento, se bloquea automáticamente. Nada aparece en el Android Monitor que tiene en rojo "No connected device" y "no debuggable process".

Intento modificar el AVD modificando el "emulator performance" pero no cambia nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Pueden ayudarme ?

Comment: ¿Al darle al botón de play no te sale una nueva ventana con el AVD? A mi me pasaba que no funcionaba ya que necesitaba demasiados recursos y el ordenador no podía con la emulación. Prueba con este emulador de Android: https://www.genymotion.com/ A mi me iba mejor, y ademas es compatible con Android Studio.

Comment: Comprueba que tengas unos 8GB de RAM. Fuerza, en la propia AVD, a que los gráficos vayan por software. Puedes probar también a crear una AVD de Android Oreo, no sé por qué pero en las últimas versiones me han dejado de funcionar el resto de API's.

Answer (score -1):

El mensaje

> "No connected device"

indica que no tienes conectado un dispositivo físico o no se esta ejecutando un emulador.

Si no tienes un dispositivo físico o no se esta ejecutando un emulador, obviamente no puedes ver ningún proceso en ejecución, por esta razón se muestra el mensaje:

> No Debuggable Processes

---

Para iniciar el emulador puedes dar clic en el triangulo verde para iniciarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O la opción común es dar clic en `Run App` y al aparecer la ventana para seleccionar destino de despliegue (Select Deployment Target) puedes seleccionar alguno disponible:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias par tu respuesta ! Sin embargo solo aparece por debajo "Waiting for Emulated device to come online ..." Y nunca aparece el avd. Una vez apareció. Pero ya no.

Comment: Cuando entres, crea un nuevo "Virtual Device". Antes reinicia android studio.

Comment: ¿Podría ser que el problema está relacionado con el uso de VirtualBox ?